# Show alert when one div has been clicked but another has not

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Hopefully this is possible and someone can help.  Basically, I have created a package Sign Up form, so users can select which features of the package they want to include, see the price and then sign up for the package.

The user picks their choices from drop down select boxes, presses an Add button to increase the packages price and then once happy, they can click Sign Up to submit.

What I need to have happen is if a user uses the dropdown, selects an option, but does not click add, they should get a message saying to click Add before continuing if they click Sign Up.  An example can be found at http://pure.evolvedublin.com/broadband (click start under the cost calculator)

I hope that makes sense!

My HTML is:

```
<div class="styled-select">
    <select id="broadband_package1" name="broadband_package1">
        <option value="0" checked="checked">No Thanks!</option>
        <option value="1">Package 1</option>
        <option value="2">Package 2</option>
        <option value="3">Package 3</option>
        <option value="4">Package 4</option>
    </select>           
</div>
<a href="#" title="Add" class="chat calculate-total1" id="calculate-total">Add</a>



<div class="homepage-content-small">
    <h2>Happy with your new bill?</h2>

    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" title="Sign Up" class="chat signup">
    <small class="make_sure" style="display:none;">Make sure to Add your desired add on</small> 
</div>
```

The jQuery that I have started on so far is:

```
jQuery(".signup").click(function() {

    if (".calculate-total1"):not(click){
    jQuery(".make_sure").show();
    else {
    jQuery(".make_sure").hide();
});
```

At the moment, I just cant seem to find a way of do this with anything I have tried.

Thanks guys, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off from Bogdan's Solution. It sounded to me that you didn't want the ".make_sure" div to show if they didn't select anything at all so here is the implementation of that.

```
$(document).ready(function ($)
{
    var totalCalculated = false;

    $('.calculate-total1').click(function ()
    {
        totalCalculated = true;
    });

    $('.signup').click(function ()
    {
        if ($("#broadband_package1").val() == "0|No Broadband Package" || totalCalculated)
        {
            //$(".make_sure").hide();
            alert("You Can't See Me");
        }
        else
        {
            //$('.make_sure').show();
            alert("Did You Forget to Add Your Package?");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a link to the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W2aR3/11/

Comment: Hi @brandon.  That is close to what I am looking for but not exactly it.  I want the message to appear if the user has used the select option but not clicked on Add.  So, if they select any option other than the first one, they need to click Add before signing up.  If they select the first one, "No Thanks", then they can proceed as normal.  The reason for this is because the option they select needs to Add to a running total.  The running total is only updated when they click Add.

Comment: Also, I just implemented your code and it seems to show the "Your cant see me" alert for all scenarios at the moment - it doesnt seem to move onto the others

Comment: Ok I updated the code and the fiddle. I'm not sure why you were getting the same result every time.  It works like a champ in the fiddle.

Comment: Strange - its still not working for me, however, I wonder could it be due to the values in the select options?  The example I gave about was just sample data, an example of my real values would be something like `value=25|UNLIMITED NGB 24Mb`.  Would this be the cause of it as at the moment, I am only seeing the first Alert for every example and then the form submits.

Comment: Make sure that where it checks to see if `dropDownValue === 0` 0 will need to be whatever the value of your "No Thanks!" option is.  Otherwise i'm not sure how it could make it into that if statment.

Comment: Ok, a little movement here.  I noticed I was reusing an ID on the page and have rectified that to get the correct message for each of the scenarios.  Also, the `dropDownValue === 0` has helped.  What is happening though is that when I click on sign up, even though the alerts pop up, for the second Alert at least, the form should not actually sign up until the user has actually clicked Add for their package.  Is there a way to stop this happening, otherwise, it defeats the purpose of it.  Thanks again for your help with this!  Nearly there :)

Comment: did you try mixing in Bogdan's e.PreventDefault Solution?

Comment: I did now, yes, but am still having a few issues with ID's, just working through it now and will report back asap!

Comment: Ok, so I seem to have this working, thanks for your help with this!  Just one other thing.  Is there a way to have the first option be ignored?  So, if a user selects "No Thanks", they dont have to click Add?  I tried changing  `jQuery(".s#broadband_package1").change(function()` to `jQuery("select.broad option:selected").not(':first-child').change(function()` but to no joy!

Comment: So just to clarify you would like to only have change fire when the first option is not selected. Is that Correct?

Comment: Yes, basically, a user should not have to click the Add button if they are not selecting a package.  The packages being the second, third, fourth and fifth options in the select.

Comment: That was the purpose of the `dropDownValue === 0` in the if statement of the signup click event. so essentially we still assigning a value to that but if that option ("No thanks") is selected we don't care if they click add or not.

Comment: Ah, I see!  I think this is where my problem is so.  My 'No Thanks" value is not 0, but `0|No Broadband Package`.  When I change it to 0, it works, but I need it to include the extra information.  So this is probably a very amateur question, but would `dropDownValue === '0|No Broadband Package'` be the way to write this part of the code?  I have tried this but it it doesnt work.

Comment: hmmmmm. That seems like it should work. Try alerting your dropdown value `alert(dropDownValue);` just before the `If` in the submit click handler. Then you can see what value it has just before you check it.  Then you should be able to tell what you need to compare to.

Comment: Ok, so what is happening is if I try to sign up without clicking Add on No Thanks, the result I get is 0 in the Alert and then fails to proceed.  But, if I select one of the other options (and dont hit Add or Sign Up), but revert back to No Thanks and then Sign Up, I get `0|No Broadband Package` and then it signs up (no clicking on the Add button at all).  So it is as if it needs the Select Options to be refreshed or something first before accepting `0|No Broadband Package`

Comment: Ok I know what your problem is the problem was that we were defaulting   `var dropDownValue = 0` and `$("#broadband_package1").change()` wasn't being called until the dropdown had changed. so If you were to select a package and then go back to no thanks the code would have worked. I updated the code and the fiddle to fix the problem. I just defaulted the variable to the option that is selected by default. `var dropDownValue = $("#broadband_package1").val();`

Comment: I actually just realized. That we don't need the click event at all we can check the value of the drop down directly. I don't know how I missed that before. I updated the code and the fiddle above.

Comment: Perfect!  thats got it! tis working exactly as I need it to!  Thanks so much for your help with this!  Apologies for missing you over the weekend by the way, I was actually nowhere near a computer for it!

Answer (score 3):

You can with a gloval variable.

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var totalCalculated = false;

    $('.calculate-total1').on('click', function () {
        totalCalculated = true;
    });

    $('.signup').on('click', function (e) {
        if (totalCalculated) {
            $(".make_sure").hide();
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.make_sure').show();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi @Bogdan.  thanks for your answer.  I have tried to implement this but nothing seems to have changed.  When I click the Sign Up submit button, the form still moves to the sign up page and no messages are displayed.

Comment: You need to prevent that. I change the code. Added the `e` param and `e.preventDefault()`;

Comment: Thanks for the update, however, this has just stopped the Sign Up button from working completely.  Also, the messages still dont want to display regardless of whether I press Add or not

Comment: I updated the code and moved the `e.preventDefault` to the case where we want that.

Comment: Maybe the selector for the `make sure` is incorrect. Can you give me some html you have?

Comment: anything in particular I can show you?  Does the link in the post help?  By the way, the last block of code that I tried from you, the sign up button still kept submitting even without clicking add and the message also did not show.

Comment: I'm looking at the link you provided and the code I put is not there. The `make_sure` statements are commented out and there is no preventDefault. You put the code from the answer below.

Comment: Hi @bogdan.  I would just like to thank you for you help with this.  Between you and the slight amendments from brandon it looks like this is just about working now

Comment: I'm going to give you an upvote since I built off your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="is_added" value="0">
```

Add an onClick method to link for setting this hidden item value to 1 when clicked

```
$("a#calculate-total").on("click", function(){
    $("input[name=is_added]").val("1");
})
```

Check this value before sign up

```
if ($("input[name=hidden]").val() == "0")
{
    // not clicked
}
else
{
    // clicked
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Batu for your help, however, this does not seem to work just yet.  I added the input before the the a#calculate-total in the html, then the jquery to the header.  I added `alert('not clicked');` and `alert('clicked');` where relevant but everytime i refresh any page, I get an alert saying "Clicked".  Also, when I click Sign Up, the form just signs up without showing the alert.

Comment: You need to check it's value in your `$('.signup').on('click', function (){})` function. Actually i recommend putting all your elements in a `form`. Add an `onSubmit="return sign_up($(this))"` method to this form and check the value in this sign_up function. Because in this way, you can check the value in your server side code as well.

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried what you suggested (adding the click function and the onSubmit) but even though the message stopped appearing on every page, it then did not appear when it was needed and continued to submit to the form when it should not have.  Any further suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Insert an attr data-choice="false" on singup button.
When user clicked on add-button change that attr data-choice="true". 
So you can manage your conditions on that attr.